# Convert Image<Rgba32> to Byte[] using ImageSharp

Tags: imagesharp

How can I convert an image to array of bytes using ImageSharp library?

Can ImageSharp library also suggest/provide RotateMode and FlipMode based on EXIF Orientation?

Comment: Onto the second question: There's a transformation API function called `AutoOrient()`. Look it up ;)

Answer (score 17):

If you are looking to convert the raw pixels into a `byte[]` you do the following.

```cs
var bytes = image.SavePixelData()
```

If you are looking to convert the encoded stream as a `byte[]` (which I suspect is what you are looking for). You do this.

```cs
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(ms, imageFormat);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I used the latter way. Thanks.

Comment: Great. Can you mark the answer then please to satisfy my OCD.

Comment: For anyone coming along later:  Note that the image.SavePixelData() function has been replaced with image.GetPixelSpan(), which returns a Span<T> of the pixel type (which can then be turned into an array with .ToArray() if need be).

Comment: `GetPixelSpan()` returns `Span<Rgba32>`, so `ToArray()` will return `Rgba32[]`. To have `byte[]`, you can use `MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(image.GetPixelSpan()).ToArray()`

Comment: @Majid; and in order to gain access to `GetPixelSpan`, one should add `using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Advanced;` (took me a few minutes to figure out why VS couldn't find this method...)

Comment: man, u just give me the answer which i have been looking for 1 week !

Comment: https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/index.html 
Hopefully that will save you time in the future.

Comment: `GetPixelSpan` is gone now. So?

Comment: Seems [`TryGetSinglePixelSpan` should be used instead](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/discussions/1258) now.

Comment: According to the source code of the `MemoryStream` class you will not be able to store more than 2 GB.

Comment: Just to add, similar to what this answer states if you're looking to save to a particular format like PNG you can use the convenience method `image.SaveAsPng(ms)` or for JPEG 'image.SaveAsJpeg(ms)` or other formats as per extension methods at the bottom of the documentation page [SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image-1.html)

Answer (score 3):

For those who look after 2020:

SixLabors seems to like change in naming and adding abstraction layers, so...
Now to get a raw byte data you do the following steps.

1. Get `MemoryGroup` of an image using `GetPixelMemoryGroup()` method.
2. Converting it into array (because `GetPixelMemoryGroup()` returns a interface) and taking first element (if somebody tells me why they did that, i'll appreciate).
3. From `System.Memory<TPixel>` get a `Span` and then do stuff in old way.
   (i prefer solution from @Majid comment)

So the code looks something line this:

```cs
var _IMemoryGroup = image.GetPixelMemoryGroup();
var _MemoryGroup = _IMemoryGroup.ToArray()[0];
var PixelData = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(_MemoryGroup.Span).ToArray();
```

*ofc you don't have to split this into variables and you can do this in one line of code. I did it just for clarification purposes. This solution only viable as for 06 Sep 2020*

Comment: This is not a good answer and should be avoided. 

[`IMemoryGroup<T>`](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Memory.IMemoryGroup-1.html) represents a collection of uniformly-sized discontiguous memory. The first element only represents the first item in that collection.

Comment: @JamesSouth and what about trying to get pixel data in async functions? `Span`s aren't available there.

Comment: @JamesSouth Provide a solution that work at least

Comment: You need to copy each individual Memory<TPixel> in the memory group not just the first one.

P.S "SixLabors seems to like change in naming and adding abstraction layers" is a really unhelpful comment. If you were using a beta that is your responsibility.

Comment: @JamesSouth tho it's not beta

Comment: It was when the span APIs were last changed. Nothing has changed in that area since the first release candidate.

Comment: @ZecosMAX when a library's author tells you you're doing it wrong, that you're using the wrong API, it's a good idea to listen. The library's author posted the accepted, working answer.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, not really, you're not considering time period.
if you check answer's above comments you'll find this following text: "Note that the SavePixelData() function has been replaced with GetPixelSpan()"

I was using release version of a library, not beta as James thinks it was, i've checked his answer, the method was not there, i've checked Jarak's and Majid's solution. The methods was not there. So i came up with my solution. This meant that author of library just really-really likes to swap functions around, and am i guilty if by today he returns the ~handy one-liner~ ?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, and, yeah... his answer is not accepted :)

Comment: @ZecosMAX Doesn't make you any less incorrect.

I provided my answer in 2018. That was 2 years before your one.  I described a workaround in the comments above per request rather than update my answer as to not break conversation flow for readers. 

As to why I thought you were using a beta... Things changed from beta to V1 RC1  but no breaking changes were from V1 RC1 until we introduced changes in V2. So perhaps as Panagiotis suggested, perhaps listening to the library author is wise.

Comment: To get all the pixels as a single array use this instead of the first two lines: `image.GetPixelMemoryGroup().SelectMany(group => group.ToArray()).ToArray()` - though this will not work if combining the groups would exceed the maximum array size.